# How to remove xPage table borders

Tags: xpages

First question is: do I really need to use tables to align/organize labels/fields on my xPage?
It's like old style development (using hidden tables) that helps group components on the form/page.
Anyway I just switched from Notes 8 to Notes 9 and apply Bootstrap 3 theme. Now all tables have top border I cannot remove. It's something weird. Even my own class doesn't remove the border.

```
table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Moreover if I try to set border size/color it works only for left,righ and bottom. If I set border size 2px then it sets the color for top border as well

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

So how do I remove tables borders on my page. See picture below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your CSS:

```
.table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, 
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
     border-top: 0px;
}
```

You don't need a table to align label and field. Use style "display:inline-block" and set an appropriate width:

```xml
<xp:label
    value="Label1"
    id="label1"
    for="inputText1"
    style="width:20%;display:inline-block;">
</xp:label>
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{sessionScope.input1}"
    style="width:75%;display:inline-block;">
</xp:inputText>
```

Use separate classes for label and fields with those styles to set the same align to all label/fields in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you move to a Bootstrap theme you would not need the tables for alignment plus you would be creating a responsive design that could adapt to mobile devices.